# How to get Unique Values from another sheet depending on another cell value ( gSheet)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have one dynamic sheet (called totals) that pulls data from another sheet (called requirements).
I need to pull some data from 'totals' sheet into a new sheet (called packing), the value have to be unique and have to depend on another cell inside totals sheet.

in another meaning i need to do something like:

`=UNIQUE('Totals'!A2:A, IF(B2:B > 0))`

So it will get all unique values from the Col A if the value of Col B is more than 0

How to do that?

Comment: Excel or google sheets, tagged both. Which is relevant?

Answer (score 2):

You need `FILTER()` formula. First filter data based on condition then use `UNIQUE()` function to get unique values only. Try-

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(Totals!A2:A,Totals!B2:B>0))
```

#### Reference:

- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)